# Django bulk delete removes only hundred rows at a time

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, one-to-many, bulk-delete

I have two models with one to many relation between them:

```
class HomeCarrier(models.Model) 
    short_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)

class CarrierZipCoverage(models.Model):
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    home_carrier = models.ForeignKey('HomeCarrier', null=True, blank=True)
```

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#deleting-objects)

> You can also delete objects in bulk. Every QuerySet has a delete()
>   method, which deletes all members of that QuerySet.

According to the [source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/query/#QuerySet) comments

> The delete is actually 2 queries - one to find related objects, and one to delete.

I suprised when I'm trying to bulk delete 27k carrier's coverage zip codes

```
carrier.carrierzipcoverage_set.all().delete()
```

I got one delete query for each hundred rows in database. Whereas I expected to see only one delete query in mysql log for all coverage zip codes at a time.

[image: mysql log]

The question is there a way to delete all entities from the database with single delete query without recourse to [raw sql](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/)?

Comment: There is a [django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9519), it might be relevant.

Comment: On the related model _i.e._ `CarrierZipCoverage` set `on_delete=models.CASCADE` for the `models.ForeignKey`